# Rendering hair in 2.81 giving out weird results

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, hair

So this is the result I get in render preview:
[image]

And this is what comes out of render:
[image]

I haven't seen anything like this online and I even followed multiple tutorials step by step. What could I have missed?

Same result in Eevee but kinda worse:
[image]

Comment: You have another mesh in there that is hidden, but it's still set to render.  Hiding only affect the viewport, you need to disable rendering on that object.

Comment: There is a helmet like mesh that is covering part of the hair.

Comment: @Moog that was it, thanks!